# Why did the wife say "Goodbye" at the end?

Tags: archive

In the ending of *Archive*, when it was revealed that

> the main character was the one who had died and was just in the simulation,

Why did the wife say goodbye? Were they closing the archive, or was it just that

> the wife couldn't get the courage to talk to her dead husband?